# R - error: "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

Tags: r, error-handling, read.csv

I know this is a recurrent question, so I apologize in advance for cross-posting.

I am having trouble reading a model output `.csv` file that looks more or less like this (the original file has about 14,000 rows, but the columns are as they look here):

```
time    x     y       z          w      r         s         t
1980    1   0.8327  0.3402    0.2021    0       1.1729      0
1980    2   0.7886  0.3399    0.2019    0       2.3014      0
1980    3   0.7909  0.3396    0.2017    0       3.4319      0
1980    4   0.7846  0.3394    0.2016    0       4.5559      0
1980    5   0.8103  0.3392    0.2014    0       5.7053      0
1980    6   0.8207  0.339     0.2013    0       6.865       0
1980    7   0.8263  0.3388    0.2012    0       8.0301      0
1980    14  0.9112  10.3411   20.6821   3.1175  60.4644     3.1175
1980    15  0.9092  8.878     17.756    2.734   70.2517     5.8515
1980    16  0.9001  9.5232    19.0464   2.9655  80.6749     8.817
1980    17  1.0313  7.59      15.18     2.4332  89.2962     11.2502
1980    18  1.0333  6.8859    13.7718   2.266   97.2154     13.5162
```

For the command:

```
read.csv("df", header = TRUE, sep = ",", blank.lines.skip = FALSE)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
```

From what I've understood from answers to similar questions, a possible problem may be that the `read.csv` command is not recognizing the zeros in the last column as values, so the program reads it as if the first row contained one fewer field than the number of columns, and hence uses the first column for the row names.

However, when I create a "fake" table with actual zeros, blanks, or "NA" in the same positions as shown in the example above, the program has no trouble recognizing them and reading the file.

e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,3,3,4,5,2,2,6,7,3,8,9,10))
df$y <- c(4,8,9,1,1,5,8,8,3,2,0,9,4,4,7)
df$z <- c(" "," "," ",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
OR:
df$z <- c(0,0,0,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
OR:
df$z <- c("NA","NA","NA",4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
```

Could anyone tell me why is this happening?

I have solved the issue as suggested by other users:

```
df <- read.csv("df.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)
colnames(df) <- c(colnames(df)[-1],NULL)
write.table(df, "df.csv", sep = ",", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)

And start working as normal from here.
```

It works just fine, but I was wondering if there is a more direct solution to this problem, or if there is something I am missing.

Thank you,

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this problem to get the errors you reported (it worked fine for me). Might be helpful to put a sample of the CSV data above (instead of space delimited) from your original data file. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried argument `check.names = FALSE`?

Comment: `check.names` only affects column names; it is an inherent property of `data.frames` that they cannot have duplicated rownames (not true for a matrix).

Comment: @mysteRious, I tried that, but when I manually copy and paste from the original file to make it reproducible, it automatically converts the zeroes from my files into readable zeroes, and it works. The same happens when I do the trials with the fake data.frame I posted above, so I don't know how to provide the data so you will reproduce the error I am getting.

Comment: Can you add the argument `row.names = NULL` to force row numbering?

Comment: @Rui Barradas, I tried just in case, but does not solve the issue. I believe @aocall is right. How I understand it, `check.names` ensures names are syntactically valid, but my problem is that the program understand my first column as row names instead of actual values.

Comment: @4rj4n, yes, but then it shifts the entire data set, so I have to add an additional command to set it straight (see code above). I was wondering whether there would be a more direct way to solve the issue to make the program recognize the zeros as values, or even as blanks and then convert them.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read the last bit of your question properly. I thought it had to do with your csv perhaps not having the time label above your first column, and that column automatically being set to rownames. But I can't replicate your error that way. csv with both the "time" present or not yield the proper dataframe in R (for me). No setting straight needed. The only way I can replicate your error is deliberately setting your column one as rownames: `read.csv("df1.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", blank.lines.skip = FALSE, row.names = 1)` Why this might happen to you automatically is beyond me.

Comment: Yes, @aocall is right, my mistake. I mistook (column) names with row names.

Comment: Quick and dirty: `read.table("myfile", sep = ";", header = F, fill = T)` if you are missing one column name and then reasign via `colnames()` including the missing one

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways.

**The first** uses an external package, `data.table`. Function `fread` does the job with a warning. And the column names are messed up, since the first row has less fields than the other rows, `fread` discards that row.

```
data.table::fread("test.csv", sep = ";")
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  A  1  6
#2:  A  2  7
#3:  A  3  8
#4:  A  4  9
#5:  A  5 10
```

> Warning message:
>   In data.table::fread("test2.csv", sep = ";") :
>   Starting data input on line 2 and discarding line 1 because it has too
>   few  or too many items to be column names or data: Col1;Col2

**The second** way is more complicated. If you don't want to load an extra package, I have written a function that uses `readLines` to read in the first row with the column names and then reads the rest of the file with `read.table`.

```
myread <- function(file, sep = ",", ...){
    nm <- readLines(file, n = 1)
    nm <- unlist(strsplit(nm, sep))
    DF <- read.table(file, skip = 1, sep = sep, ...)
    if(length(names(DF)) > length(nm)){
        names(DF)[(length(names(DF)) - length(nm) + 1):length(names(DF))] <- nm
    } else names(DF) <- nm
    DF
}

myread("test.csv", sep = ";")
#  V1 Col1 Col2
#1  A    1    6
#2  A    2    7
#3  A    3    8
#4  A    4    9
#5  A    5   10
```

**FILE**

Here are the contents of the file. Note that the column separator is a semi-colon, in most continental Europe, we use the comma as a decimals marker and so the CSV format separates the columns with a semi-colon.

```
Col1;Col2
A;1;6
A;2;7
A;3;8
A;4;9
A;5;10
```

Comment: Thanks, @ Rui Barradas. The first is a nice option. In my case, however, at least the first ten rows (the number changes from file to file) have this unrecognizable "zero" in the last column, so I would need to skip a fair amount of lines to make that work. It's a nice function to have in mind, though! I like the second option. Never occurred to me reading the header line separately. Thanks. A little more verbose than the roundabout I was using, but works!

Comment: @ebb If you need to skip more rows, it is easy to add another argument to `myread`. I would set a default value in the function definition, `skip = 1`, and then the read itself would become somethinglike `DF <- read.table(file, skip = skip, sep = sep, ...)`.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas. The problem is that this files are outputs from a model and the number of rows with "unreadable zeros" in the last column is unpredictable, so I can not set a default number of rows to skip. It'll be a very helpful tool in additional codes though. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the help page for `read.csv`:

> If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer
>             field than the number of columns, the first column in the
>             input is used for the row names.  Otherwise if ‘row.names’ is
>             missing, the rows are numbered.

Without seeing the CSV it is difficult to tell, but it does seem that it must fulfil the criteria listed (ie, there is one fewer entry in the first row, possibly due to an empty column name).

Comment: Yes, that is where I got the explanation above, but I don't know how to convert the "zeros" from my `csv` into real zeros so they will be readable as actual values to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

my 'row.names' problem was that i was simply using the wrong 'sep'